# React app vulnerabilites issue with npm install

Tags: npm

I am currently learning Academind React course. I downloaded starting setup zip file and unzipped it. Open with vscode and run "npm install" in terminal as per instructions. But I am facing with vulnerabilities issue. I have tried running "npm audit fix" and "npm audit fix --force". I deleted the folder and tried again. None solved the problem. Please help me

[image: 1]

Comment: There is no magic solution here, packages you are using or their dependencies have known vulnerabilities. You will have to update to a version of the package where the issue is fixed (if available), don't use the package with the issue or run `npm audit` read about the vulnerability and see if you care about it. Having vulnerabilities does not stop you from running your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can change dependencies or development depecencies version on package.json with new version example "react" : "^16.0.0" to "react" : "~16.0.0". next run npm install it will be automatic update version

i suggest you to use the version on the tutorial because if you use new version maybe there are some code changes